# How to write a Doctrine2 delete query

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm

How do i write a query `DELETE FROM table WHERE id = 2` in doctrine2 in Zend ?

```
$this->_em->getrepository(something\entitity\something\table)->remove()->where('id',2) ?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [DELETE queries](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#delete-queries)

```php
$repository = $this->_em->getRepository('My\\Entity');
$query = $repository->createQuery('DELETE FROM entity e WHERE e.id = ?1');
$query->setParameter(1, $id);
$query->execute();
```